# Tweets scraping using Python selinum

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, twitter

I am trying to scrape tweets under a hashtag using Python selinum and I use the following code to scroll down
`driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')`

The problem is that selinum only scrapes shown tweets (only 3 tweets) and then scroll down to the end of the page and load more tweets and scrape 3 new tweets missing a lot of tweets in between.

Is there a way to show all tweets and then scroll down and show all new tweets or at least some new tweets (I've a mechasm to filter already scraped rweets) ?

Note I'm running my script on GCP VM so I can't rotate the screen.

I think that I can make the script keeps pressing the down arrow by that I can display tweets one by one and scrape them and also keep loading more tweets, but I think that this will slow down the scraper so much.

Comment: why not use the Twitter API?

Comment: It has a lot of limits like number of tweets (I think only it gets you 100 tweet) also it doesn't give you old tweets only tweets from 7 days ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll down the page by pixels, so the page will get the time to load the data, try the below code:

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 800);")  # you can increase or decrease the scrolling height, i.e - '800'
    sleep(1)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll down page in selenium we need to write

```
driver.execute_script(
        "window.scrollTo(" + str(data.location["x"]) + ", " + str(data.location["y"]) + ")")
```

Here data is the tweets that we get

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).